# How to run this code in less than 1 second?

Tags: c++, search, binary

How can I solve this problem without getting time limit exceeded

http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/474/B

I tried putting all ranges in a 2D vector then looking for the desired index using binary search but it seems that the loop in the fn `BS()` takes a lot to execute as the size of the vector can be 10^6.

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int Search(vector <vector<int> > a,int key){
    int start = 0;
    int end = a.size() - 1;
    while (start <= end){
        int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
        if (a[mid][0] > key && a[mid][1] > key){
            end = mid - 1;
        }
        else if (a[mid][0] < key && a[mid][1] < key){
            start = mid + 1;
        }
        else {
            return mid;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
vector <int> BS(vector <vector <int> > v, vector<int> keys){
    int j = 0;
    vector <int> piles;
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++){
        piles.push_back(Search(v, keys[i])+1);
    }
    return piles;
}
vector < vector<int> > Range(vector<int> v){
    vector < vector<int> > ranges(v.size());
    int sum1 = 1;
    int sum2 = v[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
        if (i == 0){
            ranges[i].push_back(sum1);
            ranges[i].push_back(v[i]);
            sum1 += v[i];
        }
        else{
            ranges[i].push_back(sum1);
            sum2 += v[i];
            ranges[i].push_back(sum2);
            sum1 += v[i];
        }
    }
    return ranges;
}

int main(){
    int n, m;
    cin >> n;
    vector <int> a, q;

    vector < vector <int> > v;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int k;
        cin >> k;
        a.push_back(k);
    }
    cin >> m;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        int l;
        cin >> l;
        q.push_back(l);
    }

    v = Range(a);

    vector <int> jucy = BS(v, q);


    for (int i = 0; i < jucy.size(); i++){
        cout << jucy[i] << endl;
    }




}
```

Comment: how fast is it running now?

Comment: it runs at more than 1000 ms at test case 3 when n approches 10^5

Comment: Hows about you not needlessly copy the input vectors (the params) on each invoke? wtb a reference.

Comment: Reduce loop usage if possible. Linear loops (while loops, and for loops that go from A to Z) are very bad compared to other algorithms. You'll learn that from a Data Structures and Algorithms class if you take one.

Comment: You are using the wrong data structure and the wrong algorithm. See the highest rated answer, which uses the right data structure and the right algorithm.

Comment: "When in doubt, use brute force." I'd just build a vector of pile numbers indexed by worm numbers. Wastes storage, but you're allowed (far) more than enough anyway.

Comment: @David: He's actually using the right algorithm (binary search over a cumulative-sum array). His data structure is highly redundant and has an extra level of indirection/pointers, though: He's storing a vector of `(end[i-1], start[i])` pairs, where each pair is a 2-element `vector<int>`.  I'm not sure what compiler options codeforces.com uses, but it's possible that passing `v` by value, not by reference, is doing a deep copy every time through the `BS` loop. gcc might avoid it when inlining. (Also, reading/printing on the fly would prob. be better here, rather than storing all the `q` vals.)

Answer (score 6):

In fact i don`t think you need 2D vector at all, you need just 1D. Which for example would look like this [2,9,12,16,25], the upper bound of each pile, you can construct this really easy. Then for every juicy worm you do binary search in that manner that it returns index with value greater or equal to the value you are looking for. The index you got from the search is the pile you are looking for.

Some pseudo-code:

```
A[n] - vector of upper bounds

A[0] = a0

For each 0<i<=n A[i]=A[i-1]+ai

For each q do std lower_bound on A looking for q,
```

the index you get is with first value equal or greater than q, so the pile where is q.

and C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    cin >> n;

    vector<int>A;
    A.resize(n);

    int ai;
    cin >> ai;
    A[0]=ai;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        cin >> ai;
        A[i]=A[i-1]+ai;
    }

    cin >> m;
    int q;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        cin >> q;
        cout << std::distance(A.begin(),std::lower_bound(A.begin(),A.end(),q))+1<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You have to add +1 to distance because the piles are numbered from 1. Work for the example, and looks pretty fast.

Comment: If you hadn't posted this, I would have. This is the obvious answer.  There's no need for a vector of vectors here. Building `A` is O(n), and searching for the `m` values of `q`_`i` is O(m*log(n)). Fast and simple.

Comment: very nice, `std::lower_bound` has exactly the right logic for the needed binary search.  Codeforces.com's time requirements for the problem are lenient enough that a perl solution passes.  (Using this fairly-obvious solution we both thought of.)

Comment: BTW, you can save a few cycles by keeping the old `ai` in a temporary variable, instead of referencing `A[i-1]` for it.  `g++ -O3` on amd64 keeps a pointer to the current position in `A` in `%rbx`, loading `A[i-1]` before use after every call to `cin >>`.  I guess it wasn't able to prove that the function call doesn't modify `A[i-1]`.  Yes, I know the function call will take a couple orders of magnitude more time than saving a load from L1 cache, I just thought it was interesting since I was looking at the asm anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious optimization opportunity is, instead of using a `vector<vector<int>>` use a `vector<int>` and manually adjust the 2D indices to 1D. You can write a simple wrapper class that does this for you.

The reason that that will be much faster is that then all the memory will be allocated as a single contiguous unit. If you have a vector of vectors, then each row will be somewhere else and you'll have lots of cache misses.

Here's a code example:

```
struct 2D_Vector {
  std::vector<int> me_;
  int ncols_;
  2D_Vector(int nrows, int ncols) : me(nrows * ncols), ncols_(ncols) {}

  int & get(int y, int x) { return me_[y * ncols_ + x]; }
  const int & get(int y, int x) const { return me_[y * ncols_ + x]; }

  ...
};
```

If you preallocate this with all the space that it will need, then it should use memory very efficiently.

Also, passing large function parameters by value instead of by reference is very wasteful, because it results in needless copies being made and destroyed. (Like WhozCraig pointed out.)

Comment: I dont understand how can I adjust the 2D indices to 1D?

Comment: @JoeEhab12: In your case, you should have used a vector of `struct { int start, end; }` instead of a vector of vectors.  (Actually, you should have noticed the redundancy between the end of one pile and the start of the next, and used just a single vector.)

Comment: @JoeEhab12: But to answer your question, rectangular 2D arrays with indices `[i][j]` look the same in memory as linear arrays with index `[i*n + j]`.  A vector of vectors isn't the same as a 2D array, though: each element can be a different length, so it can be a *ragged* array.  If you're not going to take advantage of this, don't use it, because it means the outer vector is storing pointers (and lengths, and amount of reserved space), not the data directly.  So there's an extra pointer-chasing step to access `v[i][0]`.