# Is there anything faster than vector?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, vector

I am trying to submit a challenge for an online judge (not a live contest) and my code is *barely* over time. Since the limits involved are large, every little optimization counts -- so I am looking for places to speed things up.

I already use printf/scanf, unordered_map, etc.

But I also use vectors, like so:

```
vector<int> myVec;
unordered_map<int, vector<int> > mapToSomeVec;
vector< vector<int> > vecOfVecs;
anotherVecofVecs = vector< vector<int> >(N+1, vector<int>(1));
regularVec[index].push_back(element);
```

(these are just to show the types of declarations I am using and how I am using them).

Is there a "faster" equivalent in terms of minimizing overall runtime, based on what I've posted here?

Comment: You can `reserve()` memory for the vector, by estimating or obtaining its final length, this should avoid memory realocation every time you do `push_back()`. This is the major performance tune you could do concerning vectors.

Comment: As long as you don't copy vectors around, using C-style pointer arrays won't aggregate any significant increase in performance. Object copying by the way, is something to be avoided if you are commited with performance.

Comment: My personal experience with coding challenges, is that the algorithm matters more than data structures, with the right algorithm you will usually pass tests with far from optimal data structures. That being said, if you are looking for some benchmarks for c++ stl, I suggest this site: http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque.html. There are some really good posts.

Comment: Are you profiling your code? It's immensely helpful to see exactly which operations are slowing you down.

Comment: @user5253743 I would look up how to use the proper profiler for your platform/IDE/compiler, but in the meantime you can use the "poor man's profiler": run your code in the debugger, break at some random point, and see where you are; and do that a few times.

Comment: If you could post more information, more code or the problem It would be easier to tell. All I can suggest is 1. Always default to using vectors, use anything else only if you have solid reason. 2. Use reserve/resize if you can. 3. Use std algorithms where you can.

Comment: Depending on the population pattern, a `std::deque` could improve performance.

Comment: It might be possible to use a better algorithm in the first place. This usually has more potential than doing micro-optimizations. Could you provide a description of the problem? That being said, you could also look into parallization, e.g. a divide and conquer approach where each chunk is processed in an individual thread.

Answer (score 5):

(Man you must be doing something similar to this guy [How to run this code in less than 1 second?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32149680/how-to-run-this-code-in-less-than-1-second/32149718#32149718))

The answer I gave in that post I think will help you. Vector is not slow, but vector of vectors can possibly be somewhat improved depending on your task.

The most obvious optimization opportunity is, instead of using a `vector<vector<int>>` use a `vector<int>` and manually adjust the 2D indices to 1D. You can write a simple wrapper class that does this for you.

The reason that that will be much faster is that then all the memory will be allocated as a single contiguous unit. If you have a vector of vectors, then each row will be somewhere else and you'll have lots of cache misses.

Here's a code example:

```
struct 2D_Vector {
  std::vector<int> me_;
  int ncols_;
  2D_Vector(int nrows, int ncols) : me_(nrows * ncols), ncols_(ncols) {}

  int & get(int y, int x) { return me_[y * ncols_ + x]; }
  const int & get(int y, int x) const { return me_[y * ncols_ + x]; }

  ...
};
```

Comment: I don't know if I can get away with a single vector because in many cases I don't know ahead of time how big the vectors need to be, and the limits are too large to allocate a max subvector for each vector as a contiguous unit.

Comment: You could make a more complicated data structure that keeps track of how big each row is and allows them to be variable. Similar principle to like boost flat_set, flat_map etc. Not sure if its worth it but in the sense you are talking about its best candidate for something that might be faster in your case. I.e. its a possible optimization opportunity

Comment: @user5253743, `auto` deduces the type. This is no faster or slower than putting the deduced type, except maybe a negligible difference in the time it takes to compile.

Comment: i think auto is probably good, all that means is that the compiler will deduce the type of an expression. it can only be inefficient if it results in the compiler choosing a bad type or something that creates copies, but generally it won't do that or it will be obvious when it would (i.e. use `const auto &` when iterating usually, not `auto `) You have to figure out what type the compiler is selecting if you think its going slow, you can do that with "typeid" operator. But in general, no, auto isn't inefficient. It's fully done at compile time and the run time doesn't know you used auto

Answer (score -3):

std::map is faster than vector in some cases

Comment: map is not slower than unordered_map in some cases map is faster than unordered_map look at this [link](https://lanzkron.wordpress.com/2010/06/02/optimizing-collatz-for-klutzes/) and if you need the fastest algorithm ever, use boost library

Comment: @Sative `map` is faster for access, but not when populating it because the map is reordered every time you insert a new element on it. `unordered_map` is a "dumber" version that doesn't care for sorting, and even though its access is not optimized it can be faster if you are constantly modifying it.

Comment: unordered_map in my case is much faster than regular map

Comment: Without listing the "some cases" this answer is not very useful.